# How I run multiple regression in R while adding 100 additional rows every time

Tags: r, loops, regression

I hope to get help on the following problem in R.

I have 4 variables, `firm ID`, `sales`, `size`, `date`, for almost 4,000 firms.

I want to run this regression:

`lm(size~sales)`, while adding 100 firms at a time from the 4000.

So, the first regression will have 100 firms, the second will have 200, third will have 300 ... until reaching the last regression which includes all of the firms (4000).

The second task, is I want to save the beta coefficient of each regression (i.e. each regression after I add extra 100 firms), and then plot beta on Y and number of firms on x (from 100 to 4000) to observe how beta changes when adding firms.

Do I need some sort of loop for regressions, loop for saving betas, and loop for plotting?
Thank you for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider splitting your dataset by firms, then iteratively running `lm` using a sequence `seq(1, 4000, by=100)` to subset split data frame list:

```
# BUILD A LIST OF DATA FRAMES (SIZE = 4,000)
firms_df_list <- split(df, df$firm_id)

# FUNCTION TO CALL lm() AND EXTRACT RESULTS
lm_results <- function(n, df) {

  model <- lm(sales ~ size, data = df)
  res <- summary(model)

  p <- res$fstatistic
  c(num_of_firms = n,
    sales = res$coefficients[2,1],
    std_err = res$coefficients[2,2],
    t_stat = res$coefficients[2,3],
    t_pvalue = res$coefficients[2,4],
    r_sq = res$r.squared,
    adj_r_sq = res$adj.r.squared,
    f_stat = p[['value']],
    f_pvalue = unname(pf(p[1], p[2], p[3], lower.tail=FALSE))
  )
}

# BUILD MATRIX RESULTS WHERE ROWS ARE MODEL RUNS AND COLS ARE RESULT ESTIMATES
mat_results <- t(sapply(seq(1, 4000, by=100), function(i) {
     # COMBINE FIRM SUBSETS BY RANGE
     curr_df <- do.call(rbind, firms_df_list[1:i])

     # CALL MODEL AND RETRIEVE RESULTS
     lm_results(i, curr_df)
}))

# PLOT ALL SALES BETAS AND NUMBER OF FIRMS
plot(mat_results[,"num_of_firms"], mat_results[,"sales"], type="b", 
     col="blue", lwd=1, pch=16, xlab="Number of Firms", ylab="Sales Estimate")
```

---

To account for year and month breakdown, consider `by` (similar to `split` + `lapply`) to subset by year and then month with inner `split` (similar to above process) where each iteration runs needed model. Then, bind matrices at each month and year level for final large matrix. Note: `lm_results` now receives two more parameters for indicator month and year matrix columns.

```
# FUNCTION TO CALL lm() AND EXTRACT RESULTS
lm_results <- function(n, df, yy, mm) {

  model <- lm(sales ~ size, data = df)
  res <- summary(model)

  p <- res$fstatistic
  c(year = yy,
    month = mm,
    num_of_firms = n,
    sales = res$coefficients[2,1],
    std_err = res$coefficients[2,2],
    t_stat = res$coefficients[2,3],
    t_pvalue = res$coefficients[2,4],
    r_sq = res$r.squared,
    adj_r_sq = res$adj.r.squared,
    f_stat = p[['value']],
    f_pvalue = unname(pf(p[1], p[2], p[3], lower.tail=FALSE))
  )
}    

# BUILD A LIST OF MONTHLY MATRICES BY YEAR
firms_mat_list <- by(df, df$yy, function(sub_year){

  # BUILD A LIST OF FIRM MATRICES BY MONTH
  month_mat_list <- by(sub_year, sub_year$mm, function(sub_month){

    firms_df_list <- split(sub_month, sub_month$firm)

    # BUILD MATRIX RESULTS WHERE ROWS ARE MODEL RUNS AND COLS ARE RESULT ESTIMATES
    mat_results <- t(sapply(seq(1, 4000, by=100), function(i) {
      # COMBINE FIRM SUBSETS BY RANGE
      curr_df <- do.call(rbind, firms_df_list[1:i])

      # CALL MODEL AND RETRIEVE RESULTS
      lm_results(i, curr_df, curr_df$yy[1], curr_df$mm[1])
    }))

  })

  do.call(rbind, month_mat_list)
})

firms_matrix <- do.call(rbind, firms_mat_list)

firms_matrix
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked, however, each firm is observed on monthly basis (something I missed to mention in my initial question), so I have a column for years (some observed since 2000 until 2016, some on less time span) and a column for month that corresponds to each year. taking year and months into consideration I assume it will affect the regression output, can you please advise on how to consider years and months for each firm when running `model <- lm(sales ~ size, data = df)`? Do i need sort of loop over months and years?

Comment: Wow! I thought I lost you to the other side of internet! Sometimes we get OPs that disappear. But what exactly do you mean by account for months and years. Do you want to further split firm size by year/month or include them in regression?

Comment: Thanks!! What I meant is that each firm from firm 1 to firm 4000 is observed monthly over years, mm variable from 1 to 12 and yy from 2005 to 2016. My variables are:
`firm mm  yy size sale`
Basically, I want to run the regression to include all months in each year and then adding 100 firm at a time, i.e covering all months of all years and all 4000 firms. The code you provided I think takes all observations at once...probably we have to replicate the regression over months and years to account for time?
Thanks you once again, looking forward.

Comment: See update splitting by year and month with `by` prior to modeling runs with `split`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal example for you using `mtcars` dataset. I built a regression, adding one row at a time. I preallocate a results vector to the right then and then iterate over the rows and store the coefficient results.

```r
results <- vector(length = nrow(mtcars))
for (j in 1:nrow(mtcars)){
  results[j] <- coef(lm(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars[1:j, ]))[2]
}

plot(x = 1:nrow(mtcars), y = results, type = "p")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-04-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

> The second task, is I want to save the beta coefficient of each regression (i.e. each regression after I add extra 100 firms), and then plot beta on Y and number of firms on x (from 100 to 4000) to observe how beta changes when adding firms.

You can use my `rollRegres` package. This is almost identical the example in [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rollRegres/vignettes/Comparisons.html):

```r
set.seed(65731482)
ngrp <- 40L
n_per_g <- 100L
# create group variable
grp <- c(sapply(1:ngrp, rep, times = n_per_g))
n <- n_per_g * ngrp
p <- 1L
X <- matrix(rnorm(p * n), n, p)
y <- drop(X %*% 1.5) + rnorm(n)

library(rollRegres)
out <- roll_regres(y ~ X, do_downdates = FALSE, width = 100L)
beta <- out$coefs

# check result
tail(out$coefs, 2)
#R      (Intercept)    X
#R 3999    -0.00552 1.51
#R 4000    -0.00571 1.51
coef(lm(y ~ X))
#R (Intercept)           X 
#R    -0.00571     1.51405 

# plot 
plot(out$coefs[, 2], xlab = "Time", ylab = "slope", type = "l")
```

It gives you all the 40000 - 99 value but it does it fast so you likely will not care about the extra computation

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  roll_regres(y ~ X, do_downdates = FALSE, width = 100L))
#R Unit: microseconds
#R                                                   expr min  lq mean median  uq  max neval
#R roll_regres(y ~ X, do_downdates = FALSE, width = 100L) 740 750  771    763 772 1090   100
```

and you can subset `beta` afterwards.